# I am trying to insert data in laravel 5.3 on my mysql db,getting the following error

Tags: laravel-5.3

[image]

I am trying to insert data in laravel 5.3 on my mysql db, getting the above error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Show your migration and insertion code.

Answer (score 0):

if the field `PtypeId` is the primary key, you need to make sure that in migrations you made `PtypeId` like this :

```
$table->increments('PtypeId');
```